# Programmatically scroll pdf in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uidocumentinteraction, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I'm showing a pdf file inside a UIDocumentInteractionController, like this:

```
let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: documentsURL)
    let url = NSURL(string:"itms-books:");
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
        docController.delegate = self
        docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
```

I need to automatically scroll to the last page when the controller is shown, is there a way to do that? I didn't find one. Thanks to anyone who will send help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not a straight forward solution for this, even the documentation says it's a `UIViewController` but Xcode shows it is inherited from  `NSObject`. 
I'd recommend either rendering the PDF on a `WKWebView` or a `UIScrollView`. This will give you a room to wiggle.

Comment: Thank you so much, you confirmed my sad hypothesis! :( The point is: I need to show the pdf in a modal view, I previously used a WebView and worked perfectly but I need the user to be able to at least save the file..any hint for this? Thanks again

Comment: Maybe a custom  button with a share option and you can use `UIActivityViewController` to do the trick for you.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about a custom navigation bar similar to that one of the UIDocumentInteractionController. Last trial with UIDocumentInteractionController: have you figured out what annotations are for?

Comment: I believe they are used for the options menu so other apps can extract a meta data like information to better handle it if they were used as a share option.